# Typecasting from class to integral type

Tags: c++, templates, types, traits

In order to deal with vectors and fixed/dynamic allocation in some linear algebra problems, I built the following classes (which I would prefer not to modify ):

```
// Traits : n is the size of the vector, if -1 : dynamic allocation
template<typename RealType, int n = -1>
struct ClassAVectorTraits
{
  typedef typename LinearAlgebraLibrary::FixedSizeVector<RealType, n> type;
};

template<typename RealType>
struct ClassAVectorTraits<T, -1>
{
  typedef typename LinearAlgebraLibrary::DynamicSizeVector<RealType> type;
};

template<typename RealType>
struct ClassAVectorTraits<T, 1>
{
  typedef typename RealType type;
};

// Implementation
template<typename RealType, int n = -1>
struct ClassA
{
  typedef typename ClassAVectorTraits<RealType, n>::type vector;

  void doSomething( const vector& vec )
    {
      ...
    }
};
```

Moreover I have an interface class (which I can modify) :

```
template<typename RealType, int n = -1>
struct UserClass
{
  typedef typename ClassAVectorTraits<RealType, n>::type vector;

  ClassA ca;

  void doSomething( const vector& vec )
    {
      ca.doSomething( vec );
    }

};
```

Now I want the user to be able to **give STL vectors in input instead of LinearAlgebraLibrary vectors**, so I did the following :

```
// A class to do automatic conversion
template<typename RealType, int n = -1>
struct Field : public ClassAVectorTraits<RealType,n>::type
{
  // Constructor NOT explicit
  Field( const std::vector<RealType>& vec )
    {
      // Copy vec into this (a LinearAlgebraLibrary vector)
    }
}

template<typename RealType>
struct Field<RealType, 1> { }; // Can't derive from integral type : RealType !

// And to classes to tag the solution 
template<typename RealType, int n>
struct USE_LINEAR_ALGEBRA_LIBRARY
{
  typedef typename ClassAVectorTraits<RealType,n>::type vector;
};

template<typename RealType, int n>
struct USE_STL
{
  typedef typename Field<RealType,n> vector;
};
```

And finally :

```
template<typename RealType, int n = -1, class VectorTag = USE_LINEAR_ALGEBRA_LIBRARY<RealType, n> >
struct UserClass
{
  typedef typename VectorTag::vector vector;

  ClassA ca;

  void doSomething( const vector& vec )
    {
      ca.doSomething( vec );
    }

};
```

And therefore, if we use the USE_STL tag, there is an automatic conversion :

```
UserClass<double, 2, USE_STL<double, 2> > userClass;
std::vector<double> vecSTL(2, 12.0);

userClass.doSomething( vecSTL ); // vecSTL is converted to LinearAlgebraLibrary::FixedSizeVector<double, 2>
```

**My question** : how can I deal with the `n=1` case in which the vector type is an integral type. How can I define an implicit conversion between STL vector of double (size == 1) with a `double` ?

Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: First of all, `ca` (the data member of `UserClass`) is incorrectly typed as `ClassA`. It should be `ClassA<RealType,n>`. Given this, the underlying problem is that in `doSomething` you make use of `ca`, a member whose type is fixed once and for all at compile time. Since `n` is a parameter of that type, you can't change it at run time. But the length of the input `std::vector` is only known at run time.

Comment: What advantage is there to `struct ClassAVectorTraits<T, 1>` over the `FixedSizeVector` version? A fixed-size vector should be an array, which has no overhead in C++. You should add any extra desired interface features to `FixedSizeVector` and eliminate the abuse of scalar types.

Comment: @Morwenn I would have to modify std::vector class which is not possible. I think I didn't understand your suggestion, could you explain ? thanks.

Comment: @jogojapan You are right about the UserClass member. Real type and size are fixed at compile type but it is not a problem if you give stl vector of the right size. As you can see the USE_STL tag take the same template parameters which ensure the consistency. All the error checking and other stuff that ease the use of the code are not given here.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I agree, that is a good suggestion. But I can't change it which is unfortunate. This is part of back compatibility considerations (it has once been used with scalar).

Comment: @gleeen.gould If you're looking for a solution that uses implicit conversions somewhere, then between `T` and `FixedSizeVector<T,1>` is the best bet. At least see if that works with the existing codebase.

Comment: @gleeen.gould But that means the users of `UserClass<>` need to select the right type (either `UserClass<double,1>` or `UserClass<double,-1>`) themselves anyway. If the users have a vector `v`, and they know there is only one element in it, and therefore choose `UserClass<double,1>`, they can as well pass the one element of the vector, `v[0]` to `doSomething` instead of the entire vector. And you make sure (by defining a _template specialization_) that `UserClass<RealType,1>::doSomething()` takes a scalar rather than a vector as argument.

Comment: The solution that you have half implemented is complex. What about the real problem to solve? Can you provide a plain text description of what you want? For size n you want either a FixedSizeVector or a std::vector. For size 1, do you still want two implementations or just one that takes a single value? Can you provide different usage examples of the different combinations? I do believe you are overcomplicating the problem. Additionally, what compiler/standard version can you use?

Comment: This is all solved in the Eigen library, maybe you can learn a few tricks from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to follow the scheme of generic template when you are about to specialize. Hope this helps:

```
template<typename RealType>
struct Field<RealType, 1> { 
   typename ClassAVectorTraits<RealType,1>::type value;
   operator ClassAVectorTraits<RealType,1>::type () const { return value; }
   Field(const std::vector<RealType>& vec) 
   {
       if (vec.size() == 1) value = vec[0];
       else throw runtime_error("wrong size");
   }
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use static_assert here?

Comment: @monkey_05_06 `vec.size()` is not known at compile time.

Comment: ...of course. That's obvious. Honestly though, I don't even remember posting this comment. I was probably asleep when I did it. ;)